# Trying to model a 3 phase induction motor circuit for a certain production line

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

We have a setup where we are monitoring the current supplied to the a 3 phase induction motor in a manufacturing plant. The current is read using CT sensors attached to the supply .
We are trying to identify current patterns during various fault situation but don't have enough data to do so. Hence, I am trying to model similar circuit in matlab simulink.

[model link](https://send.vis.ee/download/58c8f9f0b74d23d2/#wDcB9oIkvDX-MuDj851kNA)

[image]

The nameplate spec of the motor are as follows :

RPM = 1380, A = 1.05, PF = 0.74, V = 415+-10% ,Hz = 50+-5%, kW = 0.37, HP = 0.50, EFF = 66.0, Frame = 71 , AMB = 50 ,IP = 55, InCl = 'F', Duty = 87, Emcl = 'TEFC'

Am from data science background and having trouble here regarding the parameters to be set. I have used parameters from an example model on simulink except the First 3.
I have also set the voltage phases with a difference of 120 deg, freq = 50Hz and the supply voltage as `Supply Voltage = (sqrt(2) * Vrms) / sqrt(3)`
Where Vrms is the given voltage on motor nameplate, which comes to be as 338.85 for this motor.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that the readings are supposed to be in ranges of 0.6 (as in the real world reading we are getting) as the motor is of max 1.04 Amps, but here the readings are of greater values. I thought of using Gain block before scope to scale these but one of the electrical guys said I should look into setting the parameters right.

[image]

The whole project is on me now and I don't have any mentor for this domain. Any help in setting up the simulation right is appreciated. Thank you!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simscape's 3 phase induction motor block has a parameter estimator button which brings up this window.
[image]

Here, I set all the specs, which I got from the spec sheet of the motor and calculated the parameters.

Also, setting up the peaks of the voltage supplies help. Vrms * sqrt(2) = Vpeak

Answer (score 1):

To determine characteristic parameters of the motor (e.g. resistance and inductance) you could use open-circuit test and blocked-rotor test.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-circuit_test),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocked_rotor_test) The inertia parameter should be a known value (from motor constructor) as it doesn't take into account the load inertia.

If you just want some approximate values you can search online for motor data sheets with the same kW and specifics. An example is in [3](https://www.quantum-controls.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/WEG-0.37kW-2P-B5-IE3-WIMES-Data-Sheet.pdf):  on the last page there are parameters you could use.

If you can't run tests and want to exploit the data you have, you can try with some approximations and then using known equations to compute values. For example:

1. Assume stator inductance equal to rotor inductance
2. Compute total inductance using torque equation
3. Assume stator current equal to rotor current
4. Compute rotor resistance using nominal power and stator current

Comment: Well, thank you for your response. Will try you suggestions and get back asap.